# Scheduled Send API method works for 1 account, but not another. Any guesses as to why?

Tags: marketing-cloud, c#

I've been trying to troubleshoot a Delayed (scheduled) Send function on an email campaign managing program that I have inherited maintenance of.

The method in place for these Scheduled Sends works for all the emails in our primary ExactTarget account, but when we attempt to use it for our secondary account, it fails.

Near the end of the code block, the ["Create" method](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/methods/create/) call i'm using returns a status of "OK" for both of our accounts. 
**However, [this "Schedule" API method](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/methods/schedule/) that follows it returns "Error" for OverallStatus, whenever I'm trying to schedule a send for the secondary account.** Unfortunately, the OverallStatusMessage only returns an empty string "", as it appears that output has never been fully implemented into the API. As such, I am at a loss for what is causing the error.

Below is the code snippet I am using; the only thing I have altered for privacy reasons are the UserNames for our two accounts. The **CustomerKey** values used for both accounts (for *sendClassification*, *SenderProfile*) appear to be correct for each, matching up to the proper **External Keys** that I see on our ExactTarget site.

Is there an obvious issue here that I am overlooking, that would cause any emails on our secondary account (USERNAME2) to fail?

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this you may be able to offer.

---

```
public static int SendToListsDelay(SoapClient framework, List<int> lists, int emailID, string fromAddress, string fromName, string subject, DateTime sendDate)
    {
        string requestID;
        string requestID2;
        string overallStatus;
        string overallStatusMessage;
        string statusCreate;

        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var name = fromName.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("'", "");
        if (name.Length > 10) name = name.Substring(0, 10);
        var uniqueName = name + "-" + emailID + "-" + guid.Substring(0,10);

        var emailSendDefinition = new EmailSendDefinition();
        emailSendDefinition.Name = uniqueName;
        emailSendDefinition.CustomerKey = uniqueName;

        var email = new Email() { ID = emailID, IDSpecified = true };

        emailSendDefinition.EmailSubject = subject;
        emailSendDefinition.Email = email;

        var sendClassification = new SendClassification();
        if (framework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName == "USERNAME1")
            sendClassification.CustomerKey = "10815"; 
        else if (framework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName == "USERNAME2")
            sendClassification.CustomerKey = "4451";

        emailSendDefinition.SendClassification = sendClassification;

        if (framework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName == "USERNAME1")
        {
            emailSendDefinition.SenderProfile = new SenderProfile { CustomerKey = "16897", IDSpecified = true, FromAddress = fromAddress, FromName = fromName };
        }
        else if (framework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName == "USERNAME2")
        {
            emailSendDefinition.SenderProfile = new SenderProfile { CustomerKey = "99991", IDSpecified = true, FromAddress = fromAddress, FromName = fromName };
        }

        var list = new SendDefinitionList[lists.Count()];

        for (var i = 0; i < lists.Count(); i++)
        {
            list[i] = new SendDefinitionList();
            list[i].SendDefinitionListType = SendDefinitionListTypeEnum.SourceList;
            list[i].SendDefinitionListTypeSpecified = true;
            list[i].List = new List { ID = lists[i], IDSpecified = true };

            list[i].DataSourceTypeID = DataSourceTypeEnum.List;
            list[i].DataSourceTypeIDSpecified = true;

        }

        emailSendDefinition.SendDefinitionList = list;
        emailSendDefinition.IsWrapped = true;
        emailSendDefinition.IsWrappedSpecified = true;

        var scheduleDefinition = new ScheduleDefinition();
        scheduleDefinition.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceTypeEnum.Daily;
        scheduleDefinition.RecurrenceTypeSpecified = true;
        scheduleDefinition.RecurrenceRangeType = RecurrenceRangeTypeEnum.EndAfter;
        scheduleDefinition.RecurrenceRangeTypeSpecified = true;
        scheduleDefinition.Occurrences = 1;
        scheduleDefinition.OccurrencesSpecified = true;
        scheduleDefinition.StartDateTime = sendDate.ToUniversalTime();
        scheduleDefinition.StartDateTimeSpecified = true;

        var dailyRecurrence = new DailyRecurrence();
        dailyRecurrence.DailyRecurrencePatternType = DailyRecurrencePatternTypeEnum.Interval;
        dailyRecurrence.DailyRecurrencePatternTypeSpecified = true;
        dailyRecurrence.DayInterval = 1;
        dailyRecurrence.DayIntervalSpecified = true;

        scheduleDefinition.Recurrence = dailyRecurrence;

        CreateResult[] createResults = framework.Create(new CreateOptions(), new APIObject[] {emailSendDefinition},
                                                        out requestID2, out statusCreate);

        ScheduleResult[] scheduleResults = framework.Schedule(new ScheduleOptions(), "start", scheduleDefinition,
                                                              new APIObject[] {emailSendDefinition}, out overallStatus,
                                                              out overallStatusMessage, out requestID);

        if (overallStatus == "OK") 
            return -99;

        return -1; //error
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to go into the ExactTarget Email interface and start an EmailSendDefinition(User-initiated Send) that was created via the API for your 2nd account? I am wondering if it is an issue with the scheduling or with the definition itself.

Comment: @Mac :  
  
I do see my attempts showing up under "Interactions" > "Messages" > "Email" > "User Initiated", on the ExactTarget site. I am guessing that this is because the **Create** method call is working. The Recipient(s), Subject, Send Classification, and Sender Profile override all appear to be correct.  
  
I am able to successfully send and receive a Scheduled Send using this, which I believe is what you were asking (EmailSendDefinition = "email message interactions" in the user interface, from what I could tell).

Comment: When calling schedule, the ScheduleResult[] that is returned should have 1 ScheduleResult in it, check the StatusCode and StatusMessage on that object to get more information.

Comment: @Mac :  
I see the following:  
StatusCode = "Error",  
StatusMessage = "Exception occurred during [ScheduleEmailSendDefinition] ErrorID: 251714667"

Comment: Also, the ErrorCode value is 2. I'll see if I can find out anything on that ErrorID; if you happen to know the best place(s) to look for that, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @Mac :  
I think i got it working thanks to [this](https://code.exacttarget.com/comment/3807#comment-3807). Waiting on test results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took the advice of [this post here](https://code.exacttarget.com/comment/3807#comment-3807) and got it working.

Had to add a ClientId definition and pass that in my Schedule call.

Updated working code snippet below:

```
public static int SendToListsDelay(SoapClient framework, List<int> lists, int emailID, string fromAddress, string fromName, string subject, DateTime sendDate)
{
    string requestID;
    string requestID2;
    string status;
    string status2;
    string status3;

    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var name = fromName.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("'", "");
    if (name.Length > 10) name = name.Substring(0, 10);
    var uniqueName = name + "-" + emailID + "-" + guid.Substring(0,10);
    var clientId = new ClientID();

    var emailSendDefinition = new EmailSendDefinition();
    emailSendDefinition.Name = uniqueName;
    emailSendDefinition.CustomerKey = uniqueName;

    var email = new Email() { ID = emailID, IDSpecified = true };

    //emailSendDefinition.FromAddress = fromAddress;
    //emailSendDefinition.FromName = fromName;
    emailSendDefinition.EmailSubject = subject;

    emailSendDefinition.Email = email;

    var sendClassification = new SendClassification();
    if (framework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName == "USERNAME1")
        sendClassification.CustomerKey = "10815"; 
    else if (framework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName == "USERNAME2")
        sendClassification.CustomerKey = "4451";

    emailSendDefinition.SendClassification = sendClassification;

    if (framework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName == "USERNAME1")
    {
        emailSendDefinition.SenderProfile = new SenderProfile { CustomerKey = "16897", IDSpecified = true, FromAddress = fromAddress, FromName = fromName };
        clientId.ID = 65936;
        clientId.IDSpecified = true;
        emailSendDefinition.Client = clientId;
    }
    else if (framework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName == "USERNAME2")
    {
        emailSendDefinition.SenderProfile = new SenderProfile { CustomerKey = "99991", IDSpecified = true, FromAddress = fromAddress, FromName = fromName };
        clientId.ID = 217314;
        clientId.IDSpecified = true;
        emailSendDefinition.Client = clientId;
    }

    var list = new SendDefinitionList[lists.Count()];

    for (var i = 0; i < lists.Count(); i++)
    {
        list[i] = new SendDefinitionList();
        list[i].SendDefinitionListType = SendDefinitionListTypeEnum.SourceList;
        list[i].SendDefinitionListTypeSpecified = true;
        list[i].List = new List { ID = lists[i], IDSpecified = true };

        list[i].DataSourceTypeID = DataSourceTypeEnum.List;
        list[i].DataSourceTypeIDSpecified = true;

    }

    emailSendDefinition.SendDefinitionList = list;

    emailSendDefinition.IsWrapped = true;
    emailSendDefinition.IsWrappedSpecified = true;

    var scheduleDefinition = new ScheduleDefinition();
    scheduleDefinition.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceTypeEnum.Daily;
    scheduleDefinition.RecurrenceTypeSpecified = true;
    scheduleDefinition.RecurrenceRangeType = RecurrenceRangeTypeEnum.EndAfter;
    scheduleDefinition.RecurrenceRangeTypeSpecified = true;
    scheduleDefinition.Occurrences = 1;
    scheduleDefinition.OccurrencesSpecified = true;
    scheduleDefinition.StartDateTime = sendDate.ToUniversalTime();
    scheduleDefinition.StartDateTimeSpecified = true;
    scheduleDefinition.Client = clientId;

    var dailyRecurrence = new DailyRecurrence();
    dailyRecurrence.DailyRecurrencePatternType = DailyRecurrencePatternTypeEnum.Interval;
    dailyRecurrence.DailyRecurrencePatternTypeSpecified = true;
    dailyRecurrence.DayInterval = 1;
    dailyRecurrence.DayIntervalSpecified = true;

    scheduleDefinition.Recurrence = dailyRecurrence;

    CreateResult[] createResults = framework.Create(new CreateOptions(), new APIObject[] {emailSendDefinition},
                                                    out requestID2, out status3);

    ScheduleResult[] scheduleResults = framework.Schedule(new ScheduleOptions() { Client = clientId }, "start", scheduleDefinition,
                                                          new APIObject[] { emailSendDefinition }, out status,
                                                          out status2, out requestID);

    if (status == "OK") return -99;

    return -1; //error
}
```